# How to create a string mixing " and ' in python, for making a query on influxdb?

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb-python

I am trying to write the following string sentence to make a query on influx db:

`query=SELECT FIRST("price") ,LAST("price") ,MAX("price") ,MIN("price") ,SUM("amount") FROM "table name" WHERE time >= '2018-05-10T12:02:00Z' AND time <= '2018-06-10T12:03:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h)`

However since it mixes " and ' in the same string, I haven't been able to parse correctly in python.

When I try:

`query='SELECT FIRST("price") ,LAST("price") ,MAX("price") ,MIN("price") ,SUM("amount") FROM "table name" WHERE time >= '2018-05-10T12:02:00Z' AND time <= '2018-06-10T12:03:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h)'`

It says invalid syntax due to ' before the date that closes the string. I also try removing or just putting " instead of ', but it didn't work. Finally I tried something more dirty:

`query='SELECT FIRST("price") ,LAST("price") ,MAX("price") ,MIN("price") ,SUM("amount") FROM 'tablename' WHERE time >='+"'2018-05-10T12:02:00Z'"+' AND time <= '+"'2018-06-10T12:03:00Z'"+'GROUP BY time(1h)'`

but I got an empty query. I appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a literal `'` in the string, and the string literal uses `'`s you have to escape the `'` with a `\`. Same goes for `"`. Use your second example, but put `\` in front of all your inner `'`.

```
query='SELECT FIRST("price") ,LAST("price") ,MAX("price") ,MIN("price") ,SUM("amount") FROM "table name" WHERE time >= \'2018-05-10T12:02:00Z\' AND time <= \'2018-06-10T12:03:00Z\' GROUP BY time(1h)'
```

Another way to go, which has the added benefit of making your code more readable, is to use Python's multi-line string syntax which is three single or double quotes.

```
query='''SELECT FIRST("price") 
               ,LAST("price") 
               ,MAX("price") 
               ,MIN("price") 
               ,SUM("amount") 
          FROM "table name" 
          WHERE time >= '2018-05-10T12:02:00Z' 
          AND time <= '2018-06-10T12:03:00Z' 
          GROUP BY time(1h)'''
```